# struggle with js syntax when working with reduce

Tags: javascript, reduce

In the following:

```
let items = [
  {
     itemName: "Effective Programming Habits",
     type: "book",
     price: 13.99
  },
  { 
     itemName: "Creation 3005",
     type: "computer",
     price: 299.99
  },
  {
     itemName: "Finding Your Center",
     type: "book",
     price: 15.00
  }
]


function myFunction(max, {price}) {
   if (price > max) {
     return price
   }
   return max
 }
```

why does {price} return the price value for each object?  why not item['price'] or item.price? Whre do you find the answer in the documentation?  What do you look for?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: You should include your reduce call in the snippet.

Comment: Also, it is't good practise to use `let` unless you need to reassign later.

Answer (score -1):

Whenever you need to check js documentation, MDN is in my opinion the best answer, check the Array section for exmample
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference./Global_Objects/Array
You can try something like this:

```
const highestPrice = (myArray) => {
    let max = 0; //variable to return
    for(let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
        if(myArray[i].price > max){ //check current element
            max = myArray[i].price;
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Comment: in this case just the max price 299.99

Comment: Hope this is the solution you are looking for. Happy coding!